# How to get the type of a document with DotCMIS?

Tags: dotcmis

With OpenCMIS, I would use `mydoc.getType()`.

What is the equivalent with DotCMIS?
`mydoc.GetType()` does not work, because `GetType` is a method of `Object` in `mscorlib.dll`

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `mydoc.ObjectType`

This is one of the rare cases where DotCMIS naming differs from OpenCMIS naming.